# Set new window to open at center of the screen - Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager

How to set newly opened window at the center of the screen in Xubuntu? Is it possible? In Ubuntu it can be easily done by Compiz Config Setting Manager.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no need to install anything or mess with scripts. Open the settings manager, click on Window Manager Tweaks, select the Placement tab, and slide the bar under "Minimum size of windows to trigger smart placement:" all the way to the right. Every window you open should now be centered.

Comment: I was messing around with compiz before, this answer really saved me :D

Comment: Worked here, using Arch Linux, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `devilspie` with `sudo apt-get install`.

Then look at this thread: [HOWTO: Center / Re-position Windows](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=188948) .

There is an [example for centering mplayer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=188948&p=11163805#post11163805):

```
(if
    (matches (application_name) "MPlayer")
       (center)
)
```

Hope this helps!

I use Lubuntu which has Openbox as the default window manager and Openbox can position windows quite easily.

Comment: So I have to create that script for each application? That's inconvenient. How do you position windows at center on Lubuntu? I might consider Lubuntu because I just want lightweight desktop and the choice is between Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: There are two ways. One is after the window is launched, the other is before. I've written about the first way here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#Reposition_and_Resize_Windows_Without_Using_a_Mouse

Comment: That's not as simple as in Ubuntu I guess, but I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: If I want to position _all_ windows, would just `(center)` work, without the surrounding `if` and `matches` clauses?

Comment: @ignis, I have no experience with devilspie :( but you can open all future windows of all applications centered with just one command in Lubuntu (with the Openbox window manager).